# Spawning Multiple Jobs for building a kernel on Quad Core processor?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

If my Kernel's Makefiles have correct dependency information,

To spawn mutliple jobs, I should use this

```
$make -jn
```

> n = is the number of jobs to spawn

If I use Quad Core Machine like i7 4700MQ with 8 GB RAM, what should be the ideal and the maximum value of n ?

Comment: The ideal value of `n` is the one that makes the build run fastest. You have to measure: `make clean; time make -jn`.

Comment: I am sorry. But I didnt get you. Please specify more on `time make -jn`

Comment: [man time](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html)

Comment: The "maximum" value is unlimited, just leave out n: `make -j`.

Comment: The ideal value depends very heavily on what is the exact nature of the various jobs that get run. If all the sub-processes are entirely CPU-bound, then nothing more than `-j4` would make sense on a quad-core system. However, given a fair amount of I/O in various processes, that would give some empty CPU time, you can get away with higher. Run it with various values and watch for 1) keeping all 4 CPUs busy the entire time and 2) shortest time to complete the entire build. I often use `-j8` on Linux kernel builds on a quad-core...

Comment: @twalberg While all you say is correct (and back then I also have built with n>num cores), I suppose that the argument "lots of I/O make cores idle, so give them something to do" is flawed. Because, why is there nothing to do? Because I/O doesn't keep up with CPU power. More CPU power won't help there, likely ;-). The interesting part is, *is there any I/O idle time?* That scenario would benefit from more CPU power.

Comment: Another thing is, you need correct makefiles which consider all dependencies and do not secretly rely on things which have been built in sequential build order. (I suppose the kernel has been tried and tested thoroughly in this respect, so it is a general remark.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
```

It should give You number of CPU's in the system (as seen by OS). You can use this number. Also +1 to this number usualy won't hurt (it depends on project You are building, scheduler in use, etc.).